# A cryptic clue about an unusual instrument

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

This is a single clue based on the sort common in cryptic crosswords. I made it up myself and I have no idea if it will be hard or easy.

To answer this question, write (or rather type) ...

**an article about the smallest musical instrument (8 letters)**

Please explain your reasoning for each element of the clue..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is:

> **[THEREMIN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theremin)**

With definition:

> 'musical instrument'

And wordplay:

> an article (THE) + about (RE) + the smallest (MIN. as in 'minimum').